# A puzzle in tribute to J. J. Sylvester

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, geometry

About the right time of the year I say, since Sylvester's Day is nigh. AFAIK the puzzle is original; comments welcome if you know any better.

**(Edited)**
Sylvester's theorem, also [Sylvester-Gallai Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) was, according to WP, first proven by Melchior 3yrs before Gallai, with later proofs by Kelly & Coxeter. In keeping with the [most venerable tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy) of misattributing mathematical results.

Anyway, here is the puzzle.

> An oft-encountered form of the statement (e. g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191322/generalization-of-sylvester-gallai-theorem) and [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersLineProblem.html)) is equivalent to the assertion that for any finite set $P$ of points (from a given plane), either *all* points in $P$ are colinear or there exists at least one straight line containing *only 2* (distinct) points from $P$.
>
> The various extant proofs of the S-G theorem notwithstanding,
> **find a *counterexample* to this assertion featuring as few points as possible.**

This being my 1st submission, I am in doubt if a hint is indicated here.
Comments on this are welcome as well.
**(Edited** to assuage the throes of WhatsUp's anguish. With thanks for pointing the Devil in the details, by the way: **)** Well, a hint *does* seem indicated.

> No worries, o worthy contenders for the consistency of mathematics! The proofs alluded to here are ironclad and they allow *no* counterexample. Still, the puzzle stands.

By the way,

> no, $P$'s of size $\aleph_0$ do not count: you can do better than that.
>  Oh, neither does $P=\emptyset$: too easy.

Comment: There is no counterexample to the Sylvester-Gallai theorem as it is a theorem. What you are asking is a counterexample to your stated version. Thus you should perhaps say "find the tiny difference between this version and the original version which allows a counterexample to exist". Even with this interpretation, your stated version is not really logically clear, e.g. is your "plane" interpreted as two dimensional affine space over $\Bbb R$? E.g. things are totally different over finite fields.

Comment: @WhatsUp you're right of course. In my defense though, "my" stated version is not entirely mine: e. g. the intro to the (French) WP entry asserts exactly the same thing. It even href's the entry for Plane and its firmly positive (if unsatisfactory) answer to your question. Not to dispute the intro to my post does href the *English* WP, which I have not combed for discrepancies.

Comment: Even if the stated version is copied from wiki, your puzzle should sound like "find a counterexample to this version stated by wiki". It is totally possible that a wiki page contains mistakes or is not precise enough. The Sylvester-Gallai theorem, as the mathematical community interprets it, is true and doesn't have a counterexample.

Comment: @WhatsUp so maybe the combing should rather be left to the reader as an exercise and the suggestion it might yield a juicy plum, left as a spoiler.

Comment: After all, this is Puzzling SE, not MO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well... what kind of *plane* are you talking about?
>  [image]
>  In the Fano plane all lines have exactly three points and no line has all the points.

Bass's answer is to

> take a triangle in the Euclidean plane and place one point at one vertex and two at each of the other two. Again, each line through two *non-coincident* points contains at least three points and no line has all of them. (This does not violate the canonical theorem because I can trivially draw a line through just one of the doubled points).

Comment: Good question. If I accept Melchior's proof, then I guess your answer counts. Can you find a smaller set? I can't.

Comment: @FrançoisJuran it's _definitely_ the smallest non-trivial incidence atructure with three points on every line, so it is optimal.

Comment: Congratulations for answering within 15mn of my posting; I tested it with a few seasoned engineering students & teachers and they all stalled. I think my own solution is a wee bit simpler (not smaller); will you guess it?

Comment: Since we are already well into xkcd-169 territory here, this isn't the solution with the fewest points possible. 5 is enough, and you can use a regular plane. (Because it doesn't say the points have to be distinct.)

Comment: @Bass It says "finite set $P$". However the OP claims that this is Puzzling SE, not MO, which seems to indicate that we shouldn't take everything too mathematical.

Comment: @Bass it says there is a *set* $P$ of points, not a *multiset* $P$ and a *pair* of points which is a misleading translation. For French mathematicians, *une paire* is a set with 2 elements. How do you call it?

Comment: @Bass, ParclyTaxel there, hopefully I nailed it down. Not that I mind evil twists, on the contrary; including the xkcd-169 one. Except I let this one in uninvited.